# How can you change the color of the current ContentControl-Object?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to make a Short-Key, which change the color in yellow of everything what is inside the ContentControl. It has to be the ContentControl where I am currently in. (The cursor is somewhere within that ContentControl)

The problem is that you can just look for ContentContros by the title and Index but I do not need that. I need a code which knows where I am in and select everything of the ContentControl and makes it yellow.

My Code will just mark one single word, but not the whole ContentConrol-Object.

```
Sub toggleColor()
    If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight Then
        Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Else
        Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
        Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct way to determine whether the `Selection` (or a `Range`) is in a content control - it can only be done indirectly. For example by

- getting the `Range` of the selection
- extending the *start* of the `Range` back to the beginning of the document
- counting the number of content controls up to this point
- comparing the `Range` of the last of these content controls to that of the current selection, using the `InRange` method.

The following code contains a function that returns a content control object. If the function could *not* assign a content control to it, the returned object is `Nothing` and the calling procedure will not highlight anything. Otherwise, the entire range of the content control in which the selection is, is highlighted.

```
Sub TestSelInCC()
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim cc As Word.ContentControl

    Set cc = IsSelectionInCC(Selection)
    If Not cc Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = cc.Range
        rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    End If
End Sub

Function IsSelectionInCC(sel As Word.Selection) As Word.ContentControl
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim nrCC As Long
    Dim cc As Word.ContentControl
    Dim InCC As Boolean

    InCC = False
    Set rng = sel.Range
    Set doc = rng.Parent
    rng.Start = rng.Document.content.Start
    nrCC = rng.Contentcontrols.Count
    If nrCC > 0 Then
        If sel.InRange(doc.Contentcontrols(nrCC).Range) Then
            InCC = True 'Debug.Print ("Sel in cc")
            Set cc = doc.Contentcontrols(nrCC)
        Else
            sel.MoveEnd wdCharacter, 1
            If Len(sel) = 0 Then
                'Debug.Print ("Sel at end of cc")
                InCC = True
                Set cc = doc.Contentcontrols(nrCC)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Set IsSelectionInCC = cc
End Function
```